# Why does println() print this?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static

The following code prints out:

```
-7
-7
11 44 -54
11
```

I think it should print out:

```
-7
-7
-11 -44 -54
11
```

The code is:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Point {
    public static int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
    public static int i = 7;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (true) Point.x = -7;
        out.println(x);
        out.println(Point.x);
        Point foo = new Point(-11,-44,-54);
        Point bar = new Point(11,44,54);
            out.println(foo.x + " " + foo.i + " " + foo.y);
        out.println(Point.x);
    }

    //constructor
    public Point(int x, int i, int y) {
        this.y = y;
        this.i = i;
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

If I remove `Point bar = new Point(11,44,54);`
 the output is:

```
-7
-7
-11 -44 -54
11
```

In case this is relevant: To run this program (which is inside `Point.java`) I (like always) press Shift+Ctrl+F9 and Ctrl+F9 and Shift+F10. I'm running IntelliJ Idea 14.0.3 with JDK 7u76 on Win 8.1 64-bit with all updates installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `x` is `static`: there is only one instance of `x` that is "shared" for all instances of class `Point`. That's why the value gets overriden. In fact, `x` is not associated with any object but with the class itself. Note that this is not the case with variable `y`, which is an *instance variable*.

So in the following code:

```
Point foo = new Point(-11,-44,-54);
Point bar = new Point(11,44,54);
```

`x` is set to `-11` then to `11`.

Comment: I don't understand this yet.Why does printing out foo's integers show bar's integers?

Comment: @AppTime There's no such thing as `foo`'s integer or `bar`'s integer. The integer `x` is "shared" between _all_ objects of type `Point`. That's why the value gets overriden. This is because `x` is static, unlike `y`.

Comment: This is also the explanation for `i`, that `Point.i` is overwritten in the ctor by the assignment `this.i = i`. It's unfortunate that the language allows accessing a static field through an instance. Decent compilers warn about this.